# How to add link with href calling javascript function with parameter in Jquery datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, datatables

I want to call editEmployee / deleteEmployee function from datatable column Edit / Delete Link With Parameter empId value.

How can i pass empId column value in editEmployee / deleteEmployee function called from Edit And Delete links.

Below is my javascript code :

```
table = $('#employeesTable').DataTable(
                {
                    "sAjaxSource" : "/SpringDemo/employees",
                    "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
                    "order" : [ [ 0, "asc" ] ],
                    "aoColumns" : [
                            {
                                "className": "dt-center",
                                "sClass" : "center",
                                "mData" : "empId"
                            },
                            {
                                "orderable": false,
                                data: null,
                                className: "dt-center",
                                defaultContent: '<a href="javascript:editEmployee(empId);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></a>'
                            } ,
                            {
                                "orderable": false,
                                data: null,
                                className: "dt-center",
                                defaultContent: '<a href="javascript:deleteEmployee(empId);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></a>'
                            } ]
                })
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8m21q69e/

Answer (score 0):

```
table = $('#employeesTable').DataTable(
{
    "sAjaxSource" : "/SpringDemo/employees",
    "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
    "order" : [ [ 0, "asc" ] ],
    "aoColumns" : [
            {
                "className": "dt-center",
                "sClass" : "center",
                "mData" : "empId"
            },
            {
                "orderable": false,
                data: null,
                className: "dt-center",
                defaultContent: '<a data-emp_id="[add emp id value here]" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary edit-link"></a>'
            } ,
            {
                "orderable": false,
                data: null,
                className: "dt-center",
                defaultContent: '<a data-emp_id="[add emp id value here]" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger delete-link"></a>'
            } ]
})

 $('.edit-link').on('click', function () {
  var empid= $(this).data('emp_id')
  window.location.href="edit url ";
  });

 $('.delete-link').on('click', function () {
   var empid= $(this).data('emp_id')
   window.location.href="delete url ";
 });
```

Basically You need to have onclick events for each based on the class.. then fetch the empID stored in the data-emp_id attribute of the button thats been clicked and then redirect appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All For Comments.

I have solved issue by storing id in hidden input and accessing it in edit like this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#employeesTable tr', function(e) {
    var row_object = table.row(this).data();
    $("#hdnID").val(row_object.empId);
});

function editEmployee() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'edit/' + $("#hdnID").val(),
        type : 'GET',
        success : function(result) {
            // Do something with the result
        }
    });
}
```